# click paths in logs or analytics?

Tags: analytics, logging, breadcrumbs, click-through

I'm trying to see the path my users take when clicking thru a web app I have. I've got logs, awstats and webalizer on the server-side, and I'm looking to install some sort of analytical product. I don't see any breadcrumb/click path data in my log files. Am I missing it? Barring that, what analytical products (Yahoo, Google, etc) can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [GAVisual](http://gavisual.info) a small tool for Google Analytics which can show you users paths with waves (page by page) visualisation. It uses GA data for your site which was collected before.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) supports this via a site overlay that shows which links users clicked on each page.  I don't think it will do per-user tracking, but the site overlay gives you a good idea of how users in general navigate through your site.

Regardless, I would highly recommend Google Analytics - super easy to set up and really powerful.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine I'll try it anyway, but I'm looking for this in particular.

Comment: +1 for Google analytics. It does do Click through, it's free, and I've used it for a number of customers now, with great success.

Comment: I think it's maybe worth pointing out that Google Analytics doesn't track the Click Path of an individual user _by default_

Answer (score 1):

Woopra can show click-through paths in real time and on reports. It uses colors to visualize bounces (red) and popup links (green).
The downsides: free only while in Beta, and it can take a while for your subscription request to get approved.
Google Analytics does summary reports for entrance and exit paths and bounce rates, but it cannot show such a compelling picture as Woopra at the individual user level.

[image: Woopra click-through]
<sub>(source: [heeroz.com](http://heeroz.com/woopra1.jpg))</sub>