# Click path tracking on a single page site

Tags: javascript, flash, google-analytics

I have a single page site that has a flash interface and a html nav bar that changes content on the site without a page reload. The problem is the client wants to see the click paths users are going though to access content ( using html nav bar or flash ui to get there ). I know I can use the externalInterface in flash to callback to javascript on click events but there seems to be no custom way to trigger building a click path.

Basically on a page that doesn't have per-page content I want to track the path users are navigating the site ( not per-click tracking but full on path tracking ) through. Is this possible through custom events of some sort or just not possible?

Comment: Have you looked into the methods for tracking AJAX websites?

Answer (score 0):

You can try GAVisual for Google Analytics, or other options as mentioned here:

[click paths in logs or analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585986/click-paths-in-logs-or-analytics)